# Change background color of my html column (td) on condition where value(status) is 'Yes' using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table in my web page where I want to set background on column `Shipped` to red, where it's status is Yes.

My table looks like this:

```
|     Order-id        |     Item         |      Price          | Shipping         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       Item1      |        100          |     Yes          |
|          2          |       Item2      |        200          |      No          |
|          3          |       Item3      |        300          |      No          |
|          4          |       Item3      |        400          |      Yes         |
|          5          |      Item4       |        500          |      Yes         |
```

I got the value in my console using script

```
<script>
$('#myTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text();)  // Getting Yes, No Properly
        if($(this).text() == 'Yes')
        {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        } 
</script>
```

But it is not going in if statement, any help will be aprreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: td:nth-child(4) should be td:nth-child(3) ?

Comment: ok @tuckbloor, my concern is not on td:nth-child, if i remove the condition and apply the css, it set the background as red, my concern is that how to identify between yes and no, and set that particular cell as red.

Comment: Try to trim and lowercase the text before you enter your if `$(this).text().toLowerCase().trim()` <- sudo code

Comment: @fischgeek, i tried your approach, bit its not working.

Comment: Well is the code running before the table is rendered? Where is the script block located?

Comment: @epascarello , its another src="myJavascript.js" , and its working fine, but not getting the output as expected

Comment: WHERE IS IT LOCATED? Head, end of body? Is the table loaded dynamically?

Comment: @epascarello, Yes, it is loaded dynamically direct from database. And script is in head tag.

Comment: well there you go. Script in head is not going to find the table.

Comment: @ epascarello, Yeah you are right, table is rendered after the script,  now i shifted script from head to closing of </body>,and i tested html on localhost and its working fine, but on live server it still dosen't reflected.

Comment: @epascarellon, actually i think i got the culprit, after applying debugger, and hovering on $(this) it display like an object which has innerHTML and innerTEXT and which has appropriate value. may you guide how to extract that innerHTML value.

Comment: got the answer in each function we have to write  each(index, element)  
{
   if(element.InnerText == "Yes")
   {
     $(this).css("background-color", "red");
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to just set a class and than you would not need any javascript to do it. But you can use contains() to match the text.

```js
$('#orders tbody tr td:nth-child(4):contains("Yes")')
  .css('background-color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="orders">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And you still have not answered my question. Problem is something else and until you answer them, it is impossible to help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong with your HTML the javascript seems to work just fine

```js
$('#myTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
       // console.log($(this).text());
       if($(this).text() == 'Yes') {
           $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
       } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Order-id</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Shipping</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Item1</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Item3</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Item4</td>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Item5</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of using javascript to set a css color it's much better to add a class-name saying something about the state of the element. Otherwise later you will have to use `!important` (which is sh!t) to overwrite the inline style. So the better example is like so:

```js
$('#myTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
       // console.log($(this).text());
       if($(this).text() == 'Yes') {
           $(this).addClass('alert');
       }
});
```

```css
#myTable td.alert {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Order-id</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Shipping</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Item1</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Item3</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Item4</td>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Item5</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @SanCube what do you mean? It's all inside the answer, you can `Run code snippet` see if the result is as expected.. there is nothing more.

Comment: its all fine, to add class @caramba, but i am not reaching in the if condition only. God knows why it is not working on my page.

Comment: i coppied your whole html and script in simple editor to test, but its not working there also